# Making inits function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Alright so here is an interesting situation (imo)

Here's my code:

```
tails' :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails' [] = []
tails' (x:xs) = tail (x:xs) : tails' xs

inits' :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits' [] = []
inits' (x:xs) = init(x:xs) : inits' xs

eightB :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool

eightB xs ys = elem xs (tails' ys ++ inits' ys)
```

I'm trying to solve the "Needle in a Haystack" problem from Learn You a Haskell For Great Good; in my own way.

The problem I'm running into is, when I try inputting:

```
inits' [1,2,3,4,5]
```

into ghci, I get:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4],[]]
```

The function works fine for the first iteration, but for some reason decides to switch to the tail function after the first iteration (at least that's what I think is happening).

Comment: The reason is that in `inits' (x:xs) = init(x:xs) : inits' xs`, you recursively call `inits'` on `xs`, which is the tail of the list.  In the list `x:xs`, `x` is the head, `xs` is the tail; the tail of a list is privileged in a way that the init is not.

Comment: omg.  Thank you.  It's always something simple.

Answer (score 2):

@Iuqui helped me get to this answer.

```
inits' :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits' [] = []
inits' xs = init xs : inits' (init xs)
```

Comment: BTW, `init` has *O(n)* complexity, so it's worth sharing it, e.g. `let i = init xs in i : inits' i`

Comment: `inits' xs = xs : inits' (init xs)` is possible, too. It is passing back `(init xs)` so the first `init xs` gets it

Answer (score 1):

I know this is several years old, but figured I'd mention that `inits'` is not really useful for producing an implementation of the `search`/`isInfixOf` function. Your code above checks to see whether the needle is *equal to* one of the tails or one of the inits, not whether it's contained somewhere. Now if you actually do want to calculate your `eightB` function for some reason, you can do so much more cheaply:

```
eightB xs ys =
  (xs `isPrefixOf'` ys)
  || (reverse xs `isPrefixOf'` reverse ys)

xs `isPrefixOf'` ys = and (zipWith (==) xs ys)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, there is a sort of inherent `tail` function in your pattern matching in `inits'`.

```
inits' (x:xs) = ....
```

This breaks up the list into two parts

```
x = head theList
xs = tail theList
```

When you recurse, you are only using the tail part

```
inits' (x:xs) = <stuff ....> : inits' xs
```

What you really want to do is pass the `init` of the list into the recursion.  Unfortunately, you can't break up a list into `init` and `last` using pattern matching.  You can do this easily in a `where` though.

This is probably what you want to do

```hs
inits' :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits' [] = []
inits' theList = i:inits' i
  where
    i = init theList
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this for an assigment in uni: I think this a clean way to go about it. You can also write the helper function using map (put in comment above)

```
    --add x xss = map (x :) xss

    add :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
    add x [] = []
    add x (xs:xss) = (x:xs) : add x xss

    inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
    inits []     = [[]]
    inits (x:xs) = [] : add x (inits xs)

    tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
    tails []     = [[]]
    tails (x:xs) = (x:xs) : tails xs
```

Answer (score -1):

There is one huge problem with using `init` in `inits`, that is, `init` cannot return anything meaningful nor correct with an infinite list.

There are alternatives for `inits`

The simplest is

```
[ [1..i] | i <- [1..] ]
```

It will output forever. It is wise to use `take` with it.

Functions should approach total functions.

```
ins ls = [ take i ls | i <- [1..] ]

take 6 $ ins ['a'..]
["a","ab","abc","abcd","abcde","abcdef"]
```

These are infinite `tails` functions. The first, numbers only. The second, any.

```
> tlsn  =  [ replicate i i | i <- [1..] ]
> tls xs = [ replicate i x |(i,x) <- zip [1..] xs ]
> take 5 tlsn
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

This is `tails` and a transposition of `tails`, both from top to bottom

```
1 2 3 4 5    1
  2 3 4 5    2 2
    3 4 5    3 3 3
      4 5    4 4 4 4
        5    5 5 5 5 5 

> transpose.take 5 $ tlsn
[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]]
```

`transpose` will not transpose an infinite list.

What to do?

Comment: Huh? `init` has no difficulty with infinite lists.

Comment: @dfeuer of course you are right but `init` will run forever never finding the second to the last element. When `init` is used in `inits` and given an infinite list, there will be no outoput because, again, `init` will search forever.

Comment: I don't know why you think that. I urge you to try out jamshidh's answer, for example. It's not particularly efficient, but [it works with infinite input](https://tio.run/##NY4xCsMwDEV3n@IPhaZDTbMa2r3QGxgPHkQskphgC3p8RwF70ZfeE0gp1pW2rTXOLPUO5@BjwPMDrxlMxz7grWWMkujHVZSx64gN8E9USBPgS6kYm8bskbPCo3AW3LDHA5PElTC/HrDorZpxcb5@@WahhQqsDa2d). What is true is that the OP's notion of `inits'`, which is backwards from the version in `inits`, produces extremely boring results for infinite lists, with `inits' xs = repeat xs` when `xs` is infinite.

Comment: @dfeuer I tried jamshidh's `inits'` with `[1..]` and I was wrong about his but it started a list that would never end. `take` does not even work on it because there is only one list in [[a]].